# how to read an incomplete line from a Python pty.fork() child output?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pty
import os
import sys

pid, out = pty.fork()

if pid:
    try:
        for line in os.fdopen(out):
            sys.stdout.write(line)
    except IOError:
        pass

else:
    sys.stdout.write("foobar")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

prints nothing.  How do I make it print the incomplete line emitted by the child??

Comment: Running this prints `foobar` for me. Maybe add a `sys.stdout.flush()` in the else block?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi definitely prints nothing for me, just double checked.  I run Python 2.7.  Let me try with flush

Comment: @IsmailBadawi nope, even with flush does not print

Comment: Shouldn't you actually close the stream at the writer's end?  How else could Python's input routine (probably implemented via `getline`) possibly know whether it is encountering an incomplete line or whether more characters are to be written?

Comment: @MarkGaleck I am having no problem seeing "foobar" on my end

Comment: @5gon12eder can't - the problem is, I am using it in the situation, when the child may die, while emitting a line

Comment: Are you running this function from the command line? If so are you on linux, windows or a mac?

Comment: @BadKarma  I see two people without any problems, and I am definitely not seeing it.  This must be either a Python version, or some environmental setting?  ID10T I think is out of the question this time, since I pasted the code for you.  What environmental condition should I be checking for?

Comment: @BadKarma I am on Linux, a version of Fedora, yes on command line, I just do >./foobar.py

Comment: @5gon12eder you have a point.  How could it know?  I don't know.  But, for BadKarma and Ismail, it does somehow "know".  Maybe we ask them.

Comment: I don't see any output either (GNU/Linux).  I changed `except IOError: pass` to `except IOError as e: print(e)` and it tells me `[Errno 5] Input/output error`.

Comment: @5gon12eder oh, well, I was expecting originally, that in the exception code, I would be able to recover the incomplete line - the exception code is called, upon the child dying, so then Python knows, there is no more output and could possibly collect the incomplete line.  Alas, I don't know if that is possible, or if so, how to do it from the exception handler.

Comment: Yes so me and 5gon12eder see it one way, exactly the same.  And BadKarma and Ismail, see it the other way.  Why would that be?

Comment: @MarkGaleck The reason I could see it is because I was running it on my mac. I read up on `sys` tools and they're highly platform dependent and not necessarily supported across all of them. I've been doing some research on a work-around and am making some progress. I'll post an answer if I find something that works

Comment: @BadKarma  gee, thank you so much, can I buy you lunch or something :)?

Comment: @MarkGaleck Found this resource. Maybe give it a peek? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409897/ioerror-input-output-error-when-printing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is pure speculation: Iterating over an input stream is likely implemented as reading characters into a buffer until either a newline or an end-of-file condition is encountered.  If the child dies, some implementations (platform dependent) loose the remaining characters from the buffer.

Maybe using some more low-level I/O can avoid this issue.  When I run the original script on my GNU/Linux system, I don't get the “foobar” but an `IOError` instead.  However, when I change it to

```
with os.fdopen(out) as istr:
    sys.stdout.write(istr.read())
```

it prints “foobar” without throwing any exception.

**Update:** In order to read the stream one piece at a time, we'll need to resort to even more low-level I/O.  I found that the following works for me:

```
import pty
import os
import sys

pid, out = pty.fork()

if pid:
    while True:
        buffsz = 10  # Use a larger number in production code.
        buff = b''
        died = False
        try:
            buff = os.read(out, buffsz)
        except IOError:
            died = True
        sys.stdout.write(buff.decode())
        if len(buff) == 0 or died:
            break
else:
    with sys.stdout:
        # Also try writing a longer string with newlines.
        sys.stdout.write("foobar")
```

Unfortunately, this means we'll need to reassemble the buffer chunks manually and scan for newlines.  This is inconvenient but certainly can be done.

Comment: Yes, but...  of course, it reads the whole available output at once.  If the output is ongoing and voluminous, I think this would not work.  I tried to use readline() here, does not work as before.

Comment: I am sorry I don't want to, but I have to unaccept.  Because I wanted to read the incomplete line.  As it is, it reads the whole thing at once, not line-by-line.

Comment: @MarkGaleck I have improved a bit on the solution.  Hope it is more useful to you now.