# python - prevent IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error when running without stdout

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

I have a script that runs automatically on server through cronjob and it import and run several other scripts.

Some of them use prints, which naturally creates `IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error` because the script runs without any SSH / terminal connected, so there's no proper stdout setup.

There are lots of questions about this subject but I couldn't find anyone that actually **solve** it, assuming I can't remove the print or change the executed scripts.

I tried several things, including:

```
class StdOut(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def write(self, string):
        pass
sys.stdout = StdOut()
sys.stderr = StdOut()
```

and

```
from __future__ import print_function
import __builtin__

def print(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
    __builtin__.print = print
```

But none of it works. I assume it only affect the module itself and not the modules I import / run later.

So how can I create a stub stdout that will affect **all** modules in the process? Like I said, I don't want to change the scripts that are executed from the main module, but I can change everything inside the importing module. And just to clearify - everything is imported, no new processes are spawned etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modifying the builtin or changing `sys.stdout` *should* work (except for subprocesses—but you ruled those out) as long as you do it early enough.  If not, though, there's a lower level trick that's much easier:

- run your python scripts with I/O redirection that discards output:

  ```
  python foo.py >/dev/null 2>&1
  ```

  (assuming Unix-y scripts, as implied by "cron" in the question)
- or, redirect file descriptors 1 and 2 (same idea as above, but done within your Python startup rather than as part of the cron-invoked command):

  ```
  import os
  fd = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
  # NB: even if stdin is closed, fd >= 0
  os.dup2(fd, 1)
  os.dup2(fd, 2)
  if fd > 2:
      os.close(fd)
  ```

  (this particular bit of code has the side effect of making /dev/null act as stdin, if all descriptors were closed).  [**Edit**: I started with `with open(...)` and then switched to `os.open` and did not test the final version.  Fixed now.]

All that said, a good cron really should have stdout and stderr connected somewhere, and should email the output/error-output to you.  Not all cron versions are this nice though.

Comment: the first simple solution did it for me. good answer, thanks! :)

Comment: The first one is better, since it means your program can still produce normal output when run normally.

Comment: Another solution is to run the script with nohup: `nohup python script.py`. This command worked for me with a kubernetes cron job.

Comment: @Olshansk: yes, `nohup` (or at least some versions of it) arranges to have valid stdin, stdout, and stderr descriptors. The documentation for the FreeBSD version mentions only stdout and stderr; the Linux documentation mentions all three.