# How to find and delete the corrupt files using python

Tags: python, directory, delete-file

I searched and found the below code which was written in python to find and delete the empty folders in the drive.
when i try to delete the folders, it is giving the error message below.
Can i have the modified code or idea to search and delete corrupt folders and files in the drive.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('//run//media//halovivek//testing'):
    for file in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(root, file)
        if os.path.getsize(src_file) == 0:
            os.remove(src_file)

dir_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('//run//media//halovivek//testing'):
    dir_list.append(root)
for root in dir_list[::-1]:
    if not os.listdir(root):
        os.rmdir(root)
```

Error Message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/deleteEmpty.py", line 5, in <module>
    if os.path.getsize(src_file) == 0:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '//run//media//halovivek//testing/.Trash-1000/files/Songs Folder/My Music/SAD = UNNA NENA.mp3'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How are you running your phyton script? `python my_script.py`?

Answer (score 0):

> OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

In case you are running your code from a terminal, this error is likely to occur when you do not have an active `stdout`. To avoid issues with stdout, you may redirect the output from the terminal to a specified location as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52507297/2709971):

```
python my_script.py > /dev/null &
```