# ('syntax %(name,name,name)', <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x01CE60D0>)?

Tags: python, sys

Why when i run this line of code:

```
print ("syntax %(name,name,name)",sys.stderr)
```

I get the following error:

```
('syntax %(name,name,name)', <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x01CE60D0>)
```

Comment: That is fine and all, but it would really help if you explained what you were trying to do? what did you expect to happen? is there any other code that might help us help you? include it.

Comment: Are you looking for [how to print to stderr in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5574702/222914)

Comment: How is this an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an error.

When you do `sys.stderr`, you're printing the representation of it, which is `<open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at blah>`. I'm not familiar with the `sys` module, so I'm not exactly sure what you *should* be doing. [Here's](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stderr) a link to the documentation on it however.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use Python 2.x. Here, `print` is a statement and you are printing a tuple to `stdout`.

You can achieve what you want with

```
print >> sys.stderr, "syntax %(name,name,name)"
```

but this string seems weird to me, especially the `%(name,name,name)` part. But as you don't tell us what you really want to print, that's all that can be done.

If you want to use `print()` as a function, be it in Python 3.x or after using `from __future__ import print_function`, you should obey the [syntax of `print()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

```
print("syntax %(name,name,name)", file=sys.stderr)
```

Another issue seems to be the string you are printing:

```
"syntax %(name,name,name)"
```

resembles me of [String formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) where you have omitted the parameters *and* use wrong syntax.

So, depending on what you want to do,

```
"syntax %(name)s%(name)s%(name)s" % some_dict_having_name_as_a_key
```

could be what you want.