# How to print from Flask @app.route to python console

Tags: python, flask

I would like to simply print a "hello world" to the python console after /button is called by the user.

This is my naive approach:

```
@app.route('/button/')
def button_clicked():
    print 'Hello world!'
    return redirect('/')
```

Background: I would like to execute other python commands from flask (not shell). "print" should be the easiest case.
I believe I have not understood a basic twist here.

Comment: You're confusing two things here. You can call any functions you like from a handler; but the issue with print is what Flask is doing to stdout.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman and thanks for the comment! So flask is somewhat routing the print to http? What should I do to prevent this? Sorry if the question is silly :)

Comment: There are no silly questions :)

Comment: Flask does not route `print` to the response. If you are running the development server from a terminal session, you will see the output there. If you are running it through a WSGI server such as uWSGI, the output will appear in the logs instead.

Comment: How are you starting flask?

Comment: Hi @ciaran, i am starting the script from pyscripter. This should be equivalent to python myscript.py

Comment: Just to add that all have been right. Print is simply not meant here to provide output in the console.

Comment: Might be worth checking this out: https://gitlab.com/meltano/meltano/issues/106#note_105372174

Answer (score 159, accepted):

An easy way to do this is by printing to stderr. You can do that like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function # In python 2.7
import sys

@app.route('/button/')
def button_clicked():
    print('Hello world!', file=sys.stderr)
    return redirect('/')
```

Flask will display things printed to stderr in the console. For other ways of printing to stderr, see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python)

Comment: Do I really need to go over all files and add `from __future__ import print_function` also `file=sys.stderr` for every print? is there a short way to it?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the post I linked to in the original answer. There's one person recommends defining a function which always prints to stderr (you could put this in a util file that you already import). Another person recommends sys.stderr.write.

Comment: You could also save a little bit of repetition with: `from sys import stderr`, `file=stderr`. In Python 3+, you don't need `from __future__ import print_function`, that is the default functionality.

Comment: If dumping an object this seems to work `pprint(vars(myobject), sys.stderr)`

Comment: I'm using flask run to run the app from command prompt. I'm using pycharm as my IDE. In run configurations I have it set to emulate terminal in output console. When I try this, nothing prints in either the terminal or the python console. Any idea of what's not working?

Answer (score 40):

We can also use logging to print data on the console.

Example:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/print')
def printMsg():
    app.logger.warning('testing warning log')
    app.logger.error('testing error log')
    app.logger.info('testing info log')
    return "Check your console"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: See this if you cannot get the info logger to work: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/logging/

Answer (score 26):

I think the core issue with Flask is that stdout gets buffered. I was able to print with `print('Hi', flush=True)`. You can also disable buffering by setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable (to any non-empty string).

Comment: This is the best way for print-debugging, especially in small projects

Comment: What is the value that should be set in the PYTHONUNBUFFERED env variable ?

Comment: @thanos.a You can set it to any non-empty string. I updated the answer.

Comment: You can add an example like PYTHONUNBUFFERED="anything_here"

Answer (score 4):

I tried running @Viraj Wadate's code, but couldn't get the output from `app.logger.info` on the console.

To get `INFO`, `WARNING`, and `ERROR` messages in the console, the `dictConfig` object can be used to create logging configuration for all logs ([source](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/logging/)):

```
from logging.config import dictConfig
from flask import Flask


dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello from Flask's test environment"

@app.route('/print')
def printMsg():
    app.logger.warning('testing warning log')
    app.logger.error('testing error log')
    app.logger.info('testing info log')
    return "Check your console"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```