# jQuery.post() with JSON to Python Flask Results in Nonetype or literally Nothing

Tags: javascript, python, json, post, flask

I run the following code from within my HTML page with Javascript:

```
$.post(url,{'key':'Value'})
```

The Python Flask code looks like this:

```
@main.route('/documents', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def documents():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "Post Recieved"
        jsData = request.get_json(force=True)
        print 'data: ', jsData
        return "<html>Post Recieved</html>"
```

The output looks like this:

```
>>Post Received
>>
```

I find this odd because I should see the console print a 'data: *Something*' or an error.

When I change the the code to include the following:

```
jsData = request.get_json(force=False)
```

I get the following output:

```
>>Post Received
>>data: None
```

In this case 'None' refers to a python 'NoneType'.

Bottom line is that I'm having trouble posting the JSON to Python Flask and making the JSON accessible from within Flask. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550487/how-to-print-from-flask-app-route-to-python-console) Flask does not print out simple prints in the python console. Can you change that print into `print(data, js_data, file=sys.stderr)`?

Comment: since you're on python 2 you need to do a `from __future__ import print_function` first before doing that print to stderr