# What is the equivalent of Perl's 'print STDERR' in Python?

Tags: python, bash, perl, fish

I am trying to rewrite a Perl script a coworker made that you lets you bookmark directories.

The way it works is you type `go add dir` while in a folder and from anywhere else in terminal you type `go dir` and you will go to the bookmarked directory.

From what I can tell go is a bash function that calls the perl script with the following code: `cd (godir)`.  It seems that to print out anything other than a dir it prints STDERR.  When I use sys.stderr.write() in python it prints out the text but it also prints out `cd: The directory 'None' does not exist`

This is an edit because my original question wasn't specific enough.
I actually found a solution:
My fish function will eval whatever the Python script returns

```
eval (python go.py $argv)
```

Comment: I apologize, I was in a hurry and did not provide specific enough information... I'm going to edit the question with much better information

Comment: I suspect, based on the added information, that your original problem was the different behavior of `print` in Perl and Python when given a "nonexistent" value: in Perl, `print undef` will print nothing, whereas in Python, `print None` will, in fact, print the string `None`. Glad to see you found a work-around, though.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2 you can do:

```
print >> sys.stderr, """Text to print"""
```

For Python 3 the syntax is:

```
print("""Text to print""", file=sys.stderr)
```

Of course `import sys` is required in both cases to import the `sys` module.

Comment: ... possibly with triple quotes for multiline text.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981125/5531628)

> I found this to be the only one short + flexible + portable + readable:
>
> `from __future__ import print_function`
>   ...
>
> `def warning(*objs):
>       print("WARNING: ", *objs, file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: Hi dvdt, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you ever find a question that can be answered by copy-pasting another Stack Overflow answer verbatim, please flag the question as a duplicate by clicking the "flag" button beneath the question. Marking questions as duplicates makes it easier for users to find them when searching.