# How do I print to console when output is redirected to a file?

Tags: python, printing, output

I want to write results of some calculations to a file with print and print some other data like progress indication to Windows console so I can see it immediately.

What I write to console is: C:\Users\BoltKey>python program.py < in.txt > out.txt.

Is there a way to overload output redirection and print to console? Or is it just wrong and I should use file functions if I want to print to the console and into files at the same time?

Here is pseudocode:

```
for i in range(100):
     for j in range(100):
          result = getResult(i, j)
          print result  // print to output file
     consolePrint "progress: " + str(i) + "%"  // print to console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds an ugly hack to me.

Just use [`stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python) for displaying progress messages.

Comment: Should add in an example rather than requiring a click.

Answer (score 1):

You can print to stderr to achieve this (your command line is only redirecting stdout to a file). There are a couple of ways to achieve this, but a good one is found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python):

```
    import sys
    from __future__ import print_function
```

...

```
    print("Message", file=sys.stderr)
```