# Python equivalent of Perl's 'warn'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a very simple address book webapp in Python.
I'm new to Python but have had a fair amount of time writing in Perl, I want to know what is the equivalent to Perl's `warn` function in Python 3.6.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to figure this out on your own? The Python documentation is quite good.

Comment: From [Perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) "Prints the value of LIST to STDERR. If the last element of LIST does not end in a newline". [First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python) after googling "python Prints the value of LIST to STDERR".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for the equivalent of raising warnings you can use pythons `warnings` module like so:

```
from warnings import warn

warn('Your message here', Warning)
```

This will display `__main__:1: Warning: my message here` on stderr.

If you are looking for the equivalent of raising errors you can use pythons `Exception` class like so:

```
raise Exception('Your message here')
```

This will display `Exception: Your message here` on stderr.