# Is there an easy way to print Unix-style error messages?

Tags: python, printing, stderr

I want to print basic error messages from a script. They should have the name of the script (i.e. `sys.argv[0]`) then the message, and should be printed to stderr. Is there an easy way to do this using the standard library?

I've written the below (inspired by [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981125/4518341)) and put it in its own module so I can import it in my scripts, but I feel like there's a better way.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

def print_error(*args, **kwargs):
    """Print script name and anything else to stderr."""
    print_stderr(sys.argv[0] + ':', *args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). First set its format to `'%(pathname)s: %(message)s'`, then use `logging.error()` to print. For example:

```
# Setup
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(pathname)s: %(message)s')

# Print error
logging.error('Test error message')
```

Usage:

```
$ python3 test.py 
test.py: Test error message
$ python3 ~/test.py 
/home/wja/test.py: Test error message
```

See [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) for more info about `pathname` and other available info.