Docker health check - python script
I created a script in python (healthcheck.py) to check some dependencies in my container.
Something like:
    try:
        connect with RabbitMQ
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception:
        sys.exit(1)

Then in my Dockerfile I added the line
HEALTHCHECK CMD ["python", "/app/healthcheck.py"]
This seems to work fine, even when I run docker inspect I get response from health checks running
            "Health": {
                "Status": "healthy",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2024-06-11T16:41:41.275336909-03:00",
                        "End": "2024-06-11T16:41:41.543611865-03:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2024-06-11T16:41:53.544584312-03:00",
                        "End": "2024-06-11T16:41:53.805990045-03:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },


But I have two cuestions:

Is it correct to call the script python directly?
How could I add information to the Output field? I mean, how should I log into my script so that Output is not empty?

Thanks!




Why wouldn't it. be? 2. > The output is what the script echoes, so, just use print()




And mind that, if needed, Python can help you print on stderr: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15808105/2123530
