# Redirect logging to console during command

Tags: python, django, logging

In my Django application I have set up my logging to log all levels to a file, which works well.

During management commands (and only there), I want to log (some levels) to the console aswell.

How can I (dynamically) set up the logging to achieve this?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558879/python-django-log-to-console-under-runserver-log-to-file-under-apache

Comment: @Pol: I know that I can write to the `stderr` stream, but my issue is that I want a different behavior for logging within commands than views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually quite easy, all I had to do was to add a new handler to each logger I wanted to redirect:

```
loggernames = [ ... ]
level = logging.DEBUG
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(level)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s'))

for name in loggernames:
    logging.getLogger(name).addHandler(handler)
```