# Static Files With Django 1.6

Tags: django, file, css, python-2.7, static

I have spent all day and nothing works. I have seen at least 20 posts here about the same topic and they are different with different suggestions and nothing works for me.
Running Django 1.6 with Python 2.7.+
I'm trying to load the css for the polls app from the django tutorial.

project layout

```
Project
   |-polls
       |-static
           |-polls
                style.css
   |static
```

here is the settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/bri6ko/DjangoProjects/django1.6/PoolsDjangoProject/static'
```

template code

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(...)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

polls/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(....,url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',                                        {'document_root': '/home/bri6ko/DjangoProjects/django1.6/PoolsDjangoProject/'}),)
```

After running: python manage.py collectstatic, everything is collected and static folder which is on root gets populated accordingly with the admin and polls folders and files.

I start the server: python manage.py runserver everything works fine except the css is not loaded

this is what i get from the Chrome console when i inspect the html

```
....
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/style.css">
....
```

which looks fine but gives the following output

```
[16/Nov/2013 00:44:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2141
[16/Nov/2013 00:44:45] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 820
[16/Nov/2013 00:44:45] "GET /static/polls/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1649
```

Any help would be appreciated. I followed everything step by step. I don't know what to do anymore

UPDATE

```
DEBUG=True
```

full urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from PoolsDjangoProject import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'PoolsDjangoProject.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

full polls/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
   import views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
                   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
                   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$',     views.ResultsView.as_view(),name='results'),
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote', name='votes'),
                   url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                                    {'document_root':       '/home/bri6ko/DjangoProjects/django1.6/PoolsDjangoProject/'}),
)
```

And when i try to access

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/polls/style.css
```

I get

```
Page not found (404)
'polls/style.css' could not be found
```

Comment: What error message does django display (in full) if you ask for css page in your browser?

Comment: is `DEBUG` true or false?

Comment: post your entire urls files - it looks like you may have missed setting serving the static files with the devserver

Comment: move the "polls/urls.py" static pattern to "urls.py" and restart the django server; also perform `manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Your `STATIC_ROOT` is missing a trailing slash

Comment: I think the way you configured.. I should work `/polls/static/polls/style.css` if you already did `manage.py collectstatic` and restart app;

Comment: Moved it, nothing changed, still broken

Comment: also I add the slash, still nothing @Surya You are supposed to configure it that way because of namespace, it should work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 10):

I found it necessary to restart the running server after following the steps in

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial06/#customize-your-app-s-look-and-feel

in order to pick up the newly created static directory. That step isn't listed in the tutorial. I have opened a ticket requesting its addition.

I realise this answer is not likely to help your specific case but this question comes up prominently in Google when searching for problems with adding a static directory to the example Polls app.

Comment: thanks Sean, this helped and thanks for opening the ticket. Django people will help a ton of people by shedding light on this. Django is challenging enough :-)

Comment: I had the same problem using the 1.8 version tutorial. Still no mention in the tutorial to restart the server.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this still has not been addressed as of the 2.0 version tutorial almost 4 years later.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem too. My problem was that I didn't have my *main* app in the installed apps, whatever folder that has wsgi.py in it, that needs to be in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: this did make a huge difference in my attempts to solve this issue. thanks <3

Comment: This worked for me. Can you explain why we have to add the main app to INSTALLED_APPS? The tutorial doesn't say to do so.

Comment: I don't really know. I mostly trial and error'd until I got it to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem as well.

Here's how I solved it (`DEBUG=True`):

1. After creating a project and several apps, I created a directory called "static" that sat alongside my app directories (same level as .manage.py).
2. I set my static URL to `'/static/'` in settings
3. I set my static root to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../static/').replace('\\','/'))` (`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`)
4. I set my staticfiles dirs to `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), '/Users/username/sites/containing_dir/project_dir/static/',)` (assumes OSX path)
5. I added `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to my urls.py for my project

My static media is now served from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/styles.css` (assuming runserver command).

Comment if you need addition description!

Comment: What is staticfiles_dirs for? Why does everyone reference it when the direct path is static_root? It seems like I'd have to move files from staticfiles_dir to static_root anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it has to be known that Django is not responsible for serving static files on production servers. However, it does serve them when `DEBUG=True` during development for the sake of debugging.

For serving static files when `debug=true` you have to do *nothing*. I don't know why it is creating confusion among newbies on how to setup it. The below should help you create static files for both production and dev modes clearly

**Development mode** : when `DEBUG=True`

1. create your project `django-admin.py startproject mysite`
2. create your app `manage.py createapp myapp`
3. Add `myapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py
4. In `myapp` dir, create a folder `static`
5. In the `myapp/static` dir, save a file `myfile.css`
6. In settings.py, provide a valid address to `STATIC_ROOT` folder to store static files. It could be something like `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "mystatic")` if you want to store your collected files at `mysite/mysite/mystatic`.
7. run `manage.py collectstatic`; now you have to see the static file collected at the directory you mentioned above..It should also create one if its not present. You are free to put any directory.
8. test the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/myfile.css`
9. In case if its not working yet, try restarting the site.. New files are not recognized dynamically!

Comment: You don't need to run `collectstatic` to view static files in dev.