# Adding image as a background for a django template

Tags: django, django-media, django-static

I have checked a links for how to set an image as background for a `div`. I have tried various ways. But still am going wrong somewhere and would need some guidance...

Below is my directory structure:

```
frontend
    /frontend (django project)
        settings.py
        .
        .
    /webApp (django app)
        /templates
            /static
                img1.jpg
            home.html
```

In my `home.html` I have the following line,

```
{% load static %}

<div style="background-image: url({% static "/img1.jpg"%}); height: 650px; width: 1920px;">
```

In `settings.py` I have,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

But the image does not appear when the page is displayed. I get the following error.

```
"GET /static/img1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1803
```

My directory structure was different and have searched a few questions before to fit my need. I still am getting confused with the urls and assigning url for the background image. Also i want it as a `url` and not as `href` to set the `background-image`. 
How do I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django -- Can't get static CSS files to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574759/django-cant-get-static-css-files-to-load)

Comment: try `{% static "img.jpg" %}`

Comment: tried that... still the same result..

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "<absolute path to static folder>",
)
```

Comment: After a lot of searches, finally it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

try add but with proper path:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: It's yet giving 404

Comment: @nidHi How you define BASE_DIR variable?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes... I shifted the static folder to where my `settings.py` is present... And remove the `/` before `img1.jpg` in the html file... Finally it's working now...