# Client Side Validation not working in django.

Tags: jquery, django, validation, client-side

**I am a newbie to Django and jQuery. I want client side validations in my django project. This simple project is uploading a file and displaying the contents. I am currently just checking that the file field is not empty but it is not working.

Moreover, I want to add the code to validate the file such that it can only upload .txt and image files as well as the maximum size of file must not exceed 500KB. How can I add these validations in my .js file?**

### Template

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'FormStyle.css'%}"/>
       <script type = 'text/javascript' href="{% static 'validateForm.js' %}" >
     </script>

   <div class = "formArea">
   <div class = "fileForm">
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

      <div class = "formFields">
    <label for = "file"> {{ form.file.label }} </label>
    {{ form.file }}
    {{ form.file.errors }}
   </div>

     <div class = "formFields">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
    </div
```

### validateForm.js

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
$('#form').validate({
       rules:   {
            file:   {
                required: true
            }
       },
       messages:    {
            file:   {
                required: 'Please Upload a File!'
            }
       }
});
});
```

### Form.py

```
from django import forms
class fileForm(forms.Form):
     file = forms.FileField(label = 'Upload File' )
```

### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, HttpResponse
from .forms import fileForm

def uploadFile(request):
   if(request.method == 'POST'):
       form = fileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if(form.is_valid()):
         file = request.FILES['file']
         fileName = file.name
         # file.size returns file size in Bytes
         fileSize = file.size
         extension = fileName[fileName.index('.'):]
         return HttpResponse(file, content_type='text/plain')
      else:
         form = fileForm()
         return render_to_response('UploadForm.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must add this line after div tag.

```
   <script type = 'text/javascript' href="{% static 'validateForm.js' %}" >
```

I advice you create blockjs and add your js file here

Please , read this for more info

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Comment: I hope you already added this link:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js or
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: somewhat got an idea what you are trying to suggest. @mubariz 
I just installed jQuery validations library (django-parsley). Now its displaying the default error message of required field. "This Field is required". It is not displaying the message that I have added in js file.

Comment: For change error messages
try this script:
`<script>
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: "Please Upload a File!",
        });
    </script>`

P.S:If problem solved please, mark 'this answer is usefull' :)

Comment: Can not be :) Where was you write it?

Comment: `$('#formFile').validate({
       rules:   {
            file: "required"
       }, 
});`
edit your code like this
and add id="formFile" to <form>
So:
`<form id="formFile"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}`

Comment: <form id = '#formFile' enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
   <script> jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, { required: "Please Upload a File!", }); </script>
   <div class = "formFields">
    <label for = "file"> {{ form.file.label }} </label>
    {{ form.file }}
    {{ form.file.errors }}
   </div>
   <div class = "formFields">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </div>
  </form>

Comment: `<script> jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, { required: "Please Upload a File!", }); </script>`
you must write this after including jquery validation file

Comment: Problem solved after importing 
(<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>)
and
(<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>)

Comment: But now the problem is that if I download these js files and then import using
<script type = "text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.validate.min.js' %)"></script>
It doesnt work

Comment: Your last 2 comment denies each other.
What is error?

Comment: the problem is that if I add direct http links of jQuery libraries then it works fine but if I download the libraries into my js folder and then import them using 
<script type = "text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.validate.min.js' %)"></script>
js files are not imported!

Comment: moreover the jQuery validation script is also working in my html file only, if I write it in another js file then that file is not imported.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574759/django-cant-get-static-css-files-to-load

Look at this 2 link and solve your problem