# Why the css file can not be found in Django template?

Tags: python, css, django

I have created a project in Django. Also, I am using django-allauth for sign up and login.

In order to use my own templates with django-allauth, I have created a html file called signup.html in a folder called account inside a folder called templates which is outside of of all my apps `(/templates/account/signup.html)`. That works.

I tried to use some custom css file inside signup.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/account/signup.css">
```

It says that the file can not be found. Though, it is located in templates/account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django -- Can't get static CSS files to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574759/django-cant-get-static-css-files-to-load)

Comment: @scharette Every css works in my apps.

Comment: @Giannislordanou did you follow my link ? It is exactly what you marked as accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your css file must under `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`,set this in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

and put `account/signup.css` file to `/static/account/signup.css`,you can get it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/account/signup.css">
```

or

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'account/signup.css' %}">
```