# Determine if Django is running under the development server

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to determine if Django is running on localhost and setting the `DEBUG` variable in `settings.py` accordingly.

So that if I run the server locally it will set `DEBUG` to `True` and otherwise set it to `False`.

Localhost: `python manage.py runserver`
Not localhost: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: The `debug` flag is set when the server is started. Wouldn't using different `settings.py` for `localhost` and other be a better solution then this?

Comment: @PratikMandrekar Is there and easy way to do this from the command-line?

Comment: If it's just about `runserver` you could check `sys.argv`...

Comment: I'm confused by your examples; both `manage.py` lines will result in your app being accessible on `http://localhost:8000`. I know of no way (other than inspecting `sys.argv` as @Bernhard says) to differentiate between these two situations.

Comment: I'm sure you know, but just in case, runserver should not be used for anything but development and thus debug mode. Hopefully, 0.0.0.0:8000 is not for outside traffic.

Comment: I dont have my computer at hand but python's socket library has hooks for this I'm sure

Comment: Checking for `runserver` seems to do the job.

Comment: @Tyilo so you check sys.argv for 'runserver' inside your manage.py ?

Comment: @SpiXel inside `settings.py` actually. See my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell whether my Django application is running on development server or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291755/how-can-i-tell-whether-my-django-application-is-running-on-development-server-or)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As suggested by Bernhard Vallant, you can just check for `runserver` in `sys.argv`.

You can just replace your `DEBUG` assignment in `settings.py` with this:

```
DEBUG = (sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')
```

You should also `import sys` somewhere in `settings.py`.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your own question. Please update your question title (to something like "Determine if Django is running under the development server") or remove this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best approach, but it works :)
For something better you can use [django-configurations](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
import sys    
# Determine if in Production or Development
if (len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver'):
    DEBUG = True 
    #...       
else:
    DEBUG = False
    #...
```

Or you can use it as **one-liner** as mentioned by [little_birdie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2945815/little-birdie) in the comments:
`DEBUG = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')`

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, because the accepted answer throws an exception if you run manage,py without arguments.  However I do this as a one-liner:   "DEBUG = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')"

Answer (score 0):

Could not have a permalink to this accepted and related answer to your question. So, just pasting it:-

```
server = request.META.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', None)
if server is not None and server.__module__ == 'django.core.servers.basehttp':
    print 'inside dev'
```

*Of course, wsgi.file_wrapper might be set on META, and have a class from a module named django.core.servers.basehttp by extreme coincidence on another server environment, but I hope this will have you covered.*

PS: Please refer to [How can I tell whether my Django application is running on development server or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291755/how-can-i-tell-whether-my-django-application-is-running-on-development-server-or) for more details

Comment: I don't have access to the `request` when setting `DEBUG` in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

- Simpler code.
- you really should log it so you can know for sure
- this works even if it's run in an environment that starts it a completely different way other than calling `python`. There may not be `argv` at position 1.

```py
import sys

DEBUG = 'runserver' in sys.argv
print(f'DEBUG = {DEBUG}')
```